# "http error" when using Uploadify plugin for JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, uploadify, http-error

I'm using the plugin from here: http://www.uploadify.com/

I have setup a simple test case, select a file etc & I get a "HTTP Error" when I try to upload.

Here is the relevant code from my header..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script> 
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sampleFile').uploadify({
        'uploader': 'include/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'upload_test.php',
        'folder': '/work/avais/bizlists/lists',
        'cancelImg': 'include/uploadify/cancel.png'
    });
});
</script>

</head>
```

.. and here is my html code..

```
<div id="upload_wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" /><br />
    <input id="sampleFile" name="sampleFile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" name="upload" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:$('#sampleFile').uploadifyUpload();" />
</div>
```

I would provide the link but it's inside an admin area.

I couldn't find any documentation on troubleshooting errors on this plugin.

**Edit:** I checked it with fiddler & it seems I'm getting a "Response Code 413 - Request Entity Too Large" error.

**Edit:** Problem fixed.... it was an issue with some stuff I had in the .htaccess file, probably the "LimitRequestBody".

Comment: which http error? You can use a http reader like fiddler to validate debug your requests.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm not sure which http error.... all it says is "HTTP Error" when I click the upload button.

Comment: OK I checked it with fiddler & it seems I'm getting a "Response Code 413 - Request Entity Too Large" error.

Comment: Problem fixed.... it was an issue with some stuff I had in the .htaccess file, probably the "LimitRequestBody".

Comment: @Brett you can answer your own question (your solution is good info) and close it after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed.... it was an issue with some stuff I had in the .htaccess file, probably the "LimitRequestBody".

Not sure why these settings affected it as the values I had set in there were larger values than the files I was trying to upload, but alas the code I took out of .htaccess was the below..

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256MB
php_value post_max_size 300MB
php_value max_input_time 500
LimitRequestBody 500MB
```

Comment: I get 500 - Internal Server Error, why?

Comment: Perhaps user588725's answer will help you!?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did try this but the problem still exists with large files.

Comment: @AlaaSadik Are you using PHP? If so, have you checked your `max_execution_time`?

Comment: Yes, I use PHP with a maximum possible "max_execution_time" of 120, according to my hosting Plan.

Comment: @AlaaSadik I suggest creating a new question with more details; probably your best chance to solve your issue rather than go back and forth in the comments here; especially since it was a different error than I was getting.

Comment: The [correct syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) is `LimitRequestBody bytes`, such as `LimitRequestBody 102400` specifying the number of bytes with no metric unit. Otherwise, you'll receive a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 3):

I got a different http error: HTTP undefined or HTTP 500. After 4 hours of searching the web, I found the answer.

It is because the server uses Mod_Security. To turn it off, add these lines to .htacess file

```
<Ifmodule mod_php5.c>
SecFilterEngine "off"
SecFilterScanPOST "off"
</Ifmodule>
```

Credit: scaturan posted on http://gallery.menalto.com/node/94614