# Uploadify Loading Slow and Uncaught Errors

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, uploadify

So I'm trying to implement upload functionality on my site using the uploadify plugin found [here](http://www.uploadify.com/) So far here's my html:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload">
    <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('stop')">Stop Uploading</a> | <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*')">Upload</a>
</form>
```

And here's my jquery:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'auto' : false,
    'buttonText' : "BROWSE",
    'fileSizeLimit' : '100MB',
    'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
    'fileTypeDesc' : 'Doc Files',
    'fileTypeExts' : '*.doc; *.docx',
    'buttonImage' : 'Images/browse-btn.png',
    'preventCaching' : false,
    'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'upload_file.php'
});
```

And i have this at the top of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/uploadify.css" />
```

So the browse button shows up, the options all work find, but the problem is two things:
1) The upload bar won't load unless I refresh the page. The upload bar is this:
[image: Upload Status]

Is this some swf problem? I picked up a few things here and there from people saying that there are problems with loading swf on browsers.

2) When I try to hit the x on the status bar or try to click the cancel/upload links below it, the browser gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Call to StartUpload failed jquery.uploadify.min.js:16
Uncaught Call to CancelUpload failed
```

The files end up not uploading (obviously). Any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Came across the next question  , is that your case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034239/http-error-when-using-uploadify-plugin-for-jquery

Comment: @OfirBaruch not exactly, i don't have a http error. I believe my problem is that the website doesn't know what to do when I click upload or cancel. Plus my htaccess file is not that extensive, just a few rewrite conditions

Comment: @John Bernal which of the version are you using ... also did you try the HTML5 version ?

Comment: @Baba no just the flash version. And what do you mean `which of the version are you using`, do you mean which which version of uploadify? if so im using 3.1

Comment: Just want to kno wit its is version `v3.1.1`

Comment: @Baba okay..so did I answer your question then?

Comment: @John Bernal am trying to replicate this error .... would get back as soon as am able to

Comment: What browser are you using to test this? Is the problem present in any browser?

Comment: You have write your code in function like $(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
       
    });
});

Comment: @Harry why does that have to be the case? And I tried that and still get the uncaught error

Comment: @JohnBernal `$(function() {` is the equivalent of `$(document).ready(function() {` and it would be normally necessary if you bind your plugin before before the `#file_upload` element (inside the page source) to make sure the DOM was ready and the element is present. If you include the script after the `#file_upload` element, then it should work without the ready event handler, because the element is already loaded into the DOM. Since you say the custom Uploadify custom browse button is rendered, then this doesn't affect your case.

Comment: @JohnBernal Have you tried updating your Flash Plugin? (not sure if it's the case for Chrome which has the plugin integrated). It looks to me like the error is related to calls made to methods defined inside the flash component (`Call to [method_name] failed` is found inside the swfobject script included with uploadify, which is responsible for the swf embed). Also if it's possible in your case, you might want to try upgrading the Uploadify plugin as well which seems to be version 3.2 now http://www.uploadify.com/download/

Comment: @spider **ALL** my jquery is already inside of `$(document).ready(function() {`. Also wil try the updated version and let you know

Comment: @JohnBernal Have you tried the demo bundled with the Uploadify download? If that gives you the same error, then there might be something wrong with the enviroment you are testing in. Also if you are integrating Uploadify into a page that has other scripts included there might be conflicts (are you getting any other errors - maybe on page load - besides the ones related to the Uploadify plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jQuery you're using and at what browser you're getting an error. Please add below jquery version at the top of all the included js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script
```

I've pasted your all code and trying with uploadify 3.1 version and I'm not getting any error. Below is my code for your confirmation.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/uploadify.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'auto' : false,
            'buttonText' : "BROWSE",
            'fileSizeLimit' : '100MB',
            'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Doc Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.doc; *.docx',           
            'preventCaching' : false,
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="uploadForm" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload">
    <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('stop')">Stop Uploading</a> | <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*')">Upload</a>
</form>
```

This is my complete code on which I'm not getting an error. Please try with replacing your code with above code.

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your flash version. I had issues with testing on Ubuntu because its a little behind...

Answer (score -1):

**-> Check wheather your upload folder has write permissions.**

**-> Check your php.ini file for the upload settings.**

Comment: yes it does because the normal html upload works. But I wanted to make it a little fancier so I'm using this. So it's not a permission issue.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to turn auto upload On. for this just remove this line

```
'auto' : false
```

it will start uploading as soon as you add it to the queue

Comment: I put auto: false for a reason. I don't want it to upload immediately. And that's not even the problem that I stated in the post.